# Take attributes from database (SQL) and place them in label.Text in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, attributes, sqldatareader

I want to know how to place specific attribute from my database to a label, for example I want to read name of a person and place it to forms label

`SqlCommand` or `SqlDataReader` - which one do I need to use for this?

I tried `SqlDataReader` but it won't give me any result or throws a `SqlException` error.

I tried something like this:
my code is on turkish

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Ad FROM OGRENCILER WHERE OgrenciKartID=@id";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
param.ParameterName = "@id";
param.Value = _kimlik;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = connection;
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    connection.Open();

var adId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
connection.Close();

adLabel.Text = adId;
```

Thank You...

Comment: I reckon "param.Value = _kimlik;" needs to have quotes around the value like this: "param.Value = "_kimlik;""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a best practice:

```
//create connection, with a connection string
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    try {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        //Handle exception
    }

    if(conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) {
        var commandText = "SELECT Ad FROM OGRENCILER WHERE OgrenciKartID=@id";
        //"using" helps in automatically disposing of the object once it's done
        using(var comm = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn)) {
            //one of the proper ways to add a parameter, which also sets the value
            comm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _kimilik;
            //the rest is correct, assuming the connection can be established and this is valid SQL (correct DB structure)

            object result = null;
            try {
                result = comm.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                //handle exception
            }
            if(result != null) {
                var adId = result.ToString();
                adLabel.Text = adId;
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Selim check out the edited version, with proper exception handling. I was in a hurry then, but since this is going to be the correct answer, might as well make it look good.

Answer (score 1):

You can extrapolate the answer from the following, which shows how to read data from a SQL Server database, store it in a generic list of string, and then assign the first value from the list to a label's text property:

```
private List<String> _duckbillsList;
. . .
private void LoadduckbillstringList()
{
    if (null == _duckbillsList)
    {
        _duckbillsList = new List<string>();
    }
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(PlatypusConstsAndUtils.CPSConnStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(PlatypusConstsAndUtils.SelectPlatypusIdOnlyQuery, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                _duckbillsList = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(p => p.Field<string>("platypusId"))
                   .ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}

labelFirstPlatypus.Text = _duckbillsList[0].ToString();
```

### UPDATE

Okay, this one's probably easier to grok and adapt:

```
public static string GetPlatypusNameForlatypusId(string platypusId)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(CPSConnStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PNAME FROM DUCKBILLS WHERE PLATYPUSID = @PLATYPUSID";
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    param.ParameterName = "@PLATYPUSID";
    param.Value = platypusId;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;

    sqlConn.Open();

    var platypusName = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    sqlConn.Close();
    return platypusName;
}

labelPlatypusName.Text = GetPlatypusNameForPlatypusId("4F");
```

Comment: thank you but i don't need to read whole data just that two attributes this is when i want to place information of a user that is currlently loged in my program, so in log in page it reads from database and opens new mainForm on that main form is button for information about user @B.ClayShannon thank you again

Comment: How do you know my query doesn't only read one or two values? In fact, it does. You just need to take the code above and tweak it to your needs. IOW, the *precise* code you need is usually "an exercise left to the reader"

Comment: @Selim in order to read SOME of the data from your query results, you still need to access the query results.  You can't just access the part that you need without opening the datareader.  It doesn't work that way.

Comment: I tried your code but on var platypusName = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();  gives me null

Comment: @Selim: Show all the code you're using - it sounds like your query returned nothing.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon i just edited my question using your code :)

Comment: @Selim: I reckon "param.Value = _kimlik;" needs to have quotes around the value like this: "param.Value = "_kimlik;""

Comment: @B.ClayShannon it says must declare the scalar variable id (SQLException) but as you can see wrote that

Comment: @Selim: Did you try it with quotes around "_kilik"?
If it still doesn't work, try removing the "@" from the parameter assignment; I can't check now if that's a problem or not, but I'm not sure the "@" needs to be there or may cause a problem being there, because the "@" would be assumed.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon A code frome below worked for me thanks to your code, thank you a lot :)

Comment: @Selim: You're welcome; I, in turn, probably got that code from someone else here on StackOverflow, which, in effect, spreads "good viruses"